# Why onfocus and onblur infinitely calls itself?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

### ElectronicCigaretteSearchComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="soqlRequest" type="String" default="none" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="listProducts" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="offset" type="Integer" default="0" />
    <aura:attribute name="isOnFocus" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="requiredElCigarette" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="isProcess" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="allProductSOQL" type="String"
        default=" SELECT Name,AmountReview__c,AirRegulator__c,BatteryCapacity__c,BatteryCharger__c,ChargingTime__c,Color__c,DesignMizer__c,Diameter__c,LCDScreen__c,Length__c,NumberUnits__c,Producer__c,Rating__c,ServicedEvaporator__c,TankSize__c,TypeMizer__c,Weight__c,(SELECT Product2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntries) FROM Product2 LIMIT 4 " />
    <aura:attribute name="soqlProcessing" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.soqlRequest}" action="{!c.updateSOQLRequestHandler}" />

    <lightning:input aura:id="enter-search" name="enter-search" label="Search when user hits the 'enter' key"
        isLoading="true" type="search" onfocus="{!c.searchOnFocus}" onblur="{!c.searchLostFocus}" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOnFocus}">
        <div class="slds-scrollable" aura:id="scrollContainer">
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="layoutClass">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.listProducts}" var="itemProduct" indexVar="index">
                    <aura:If isTrue="{!itemProduct.PricebookEntries[0].UnitPrice != NULL }">
                        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="12"
                            class="layoutItemClass">
                            <c:ElectronicCigaretteCardComponent product="{!itemProduct}" />
                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                    </aura:If>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:layout>
        </div>

    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

### ElectronicCigaretteSearchComponentController.js

```
searchOnFocus : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('searchOnFocus!!');
    component.set("v.isOnFocus",true);
},
searchLostFocus : function(component, event, helper) {
    // alert('searchLostFocus!!');
    component.set("v.isOnFocus",false);
},
searchOnchange : function(component, event, helper) {
    let requiredElCigarette = component.get("v.requiredElCigarette");
    let isProcess =component.get("v.isProcess");
    if(isProcess != true){

    }
}
```

When I click on the  `<lightning:input aura:id="enter-search" name="enter-search" label="Search when user hits the 'enter' key" isLoading="true" type="search" onfocus="{!c.searchOnFocus}" onblur="{!c.searchLostFocus}" />` it calls `onfocus="{!c.searchOnFocus}"` and I get infinite `alert('searchOnFocus!!');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you're using an alert. When you use an alert, this causes the focus to change from the input element to the alert dialog, and then when you dismiss the dialog, the input element again gains focus, so it calls the alert dialog... You should use console.log to output messages you'd like to see instead.

Comment: ahhah) thanks for the help.